# Entry to Bali via Indonesia

Tags: covid-19, indonesia, bali

I would like to go to Bali but it is unclear whether I can enter directly under the recently-announced arrangements (I've just posted a separate question about that). Let's assume I can't.

It is currently possible to travel to Java if you can find a "sponsor", and I guess in practice that just means going through a visa agency.

Assuming I can get to Jakarta (where I'd have to quarantine) can I then travel on to Bali on a domestic flight, or would the rules for international arrivals to Bali still apply?

Answer (score 2):

Bali is a part of Indonesia.  If you can get into Indonesia by any other means, from an Immigration point of view there is nothing stopping you from traveling onward to Bali or anywhere else in the archipelago.

Note that at time of writing Indonesia *does* have [domestic travel restrictions for COVID](https://kemlu.go.id/losangeles/en/news/14343/indonesia-domestic-public-activitytravel-restrictions-extended-thru-october-18-2021), but if you have been fully vaccinated and have a recent negative PCR test, you can still travel.